# How to know, what SHELL is used when running a script?

Tags: scripting

How can I output that what shell is used to execute a script?

Ex.: the $SHELL variable gives that what is the default shell for the given user. That is ok, but the given user can launch the script with other shell, ex.: "sh script.sh" or "csh script.sh".

Using a Linux machine.

Comment: Rare is the script that can work with both `sh` and `csh`.

Comment: Those shells were just examples. The question is that how to know, with what shell is the script actually used in reality.

Comment: I don't see why this should even be a problem. Don't you use a `#!`-line in the script? This is _never_ an issue with e.g. Perl, Python or Ruby scripts, so it shouldn't be an issue for a script written for some other interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Since you specified Linux, this is doable with `readlink -f /proc/$$/exe`. That will give you (on standard output) the path the the shell executing your shell script (something like `/bin/bash`). So you could assign it to a variable (at least in POSIX shell) with `var=$(readlink -f /proc/$$/exe)`.

`$$` is the pid of the current shell; `/proc/«pid»/exe` is a kernel feature that lets you query the executable being run in a given pid, in the form of a somewhat "magical" symlink. So you can use `readlink` to get the path.

On non-Linux, you should be able to use `ps`, e.g., `ps -o args= $$` but that may wind up giving you the script name instead (POSIX allows either behavior).

Except if your script is designed to be sourced to, e.g., set variables in the user's shell, you really ought to use a `#!` line up top instead to specify which shell to run it under.

Answer (score 0):

An individual script should not have to test what interpreter it's running in. That kind of introspection is awkward and error prone and would possibly have to be implemented differently for different Unices.

For example, a Perl script can always safely assume that it's being interpreted by a Perl interpreter, a Python script is always run by a Python interpreter, and so on.  So why should not a `bash` script assume that it's being run by `bash`, and an `sh` script that it's being run by `/bin/sh`?

Testing specific *capabilities* of the current interpreter is a different issue, and e.g. `bash` offers `$BASH_VERSION` and the `$BASH_VERSINFO` array to test a version against (for example).

So how can you make e.g. a `bash` script be run by `bash` and a `csh` script be run by `csh`?  Well, you avoid letting the user pick the interpreter.

You can do that by

- Not putting a filename suffix on the script file, in case that would "confuse" the user.  A `bash` script in a `myscript.sh` file might make the user think it would be runnable with `sh`.  Instead, just call the script `myscript`, and ...
- Use a `#!` ("shebang" or "hashbang") line.

A `#!`-line goes on the very first line of the script (the two characters `#!` have to be the first in the file) and specifies the path to the interpreter to use.

A `bash` script may have

```
#!/bin/bash
```

if that's the path to the `bash` executable on your system, or if you want `bash` to be picked up from wherever in `$PATH` it's located on your system it could have,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

as its first line, for example.

This ensures that it will always be interpreted by `bash` and not by `sh` or `csh` or `python` or some other unrelated language interpreter.

The next step would be to

- Make the script executable, using `chmod +x myscript`.

Now you can run your script with

```
./myscript
```

without bothering with what interpreter to use for executing it.   In fact, to the user of the script, it would not matter *at all* whether it was a `bash` script, a Python script, or a compiled binary.

Comment: There is one case you can't use a #! line: when your script is supposed to be sourced into the user's active shell (e.g., to set variables, aliases, or functions)

Comment: @derobert I would argue that trying to source a `bash` dot-script in a `sh` script would be the same kind of _user error_ as trying to load a Python module in Perl. You just wouldn't do that.  In any case, you wouldn't try to detect that inside some polyglot script.

Comment: It'd be pretty reasonable, for example, to have one script used for all POSIX-sh compatible (enough) shells, and then only enable additional functionality when detecting bash, zsh, etc. That'd make for an easier user (and documentation) experience than a separate script depending on which shell your users happen to be using. And indeed sometimes it's actually required — e.g., in `/etc/profile`.

Comment: @derobert I do agree that `/etc/profile` may be an exception, if you need to differentiate between e.g. `dash`, `bash` and `ksh` (`zsh` uses another file, and `yash` does not read files under `/etc` by default at all).